# interfaz Comparator, sobrescribir compare

Tags: java

No consigo solucionar esta parte del ejercicio:

> La clase `ProductOrderByPrice`  implementa la interfaz Comparator, que
> es una interfaz de la API Java. Esto nos obliga a sobrescribir el
> método compare. [...]

Mi intento:

```
public class ProductOrderByPrice implements Comparable<ProductOrderByPrice>{

public int compare(Product product1, Product product2) {
    if (product1 == null || product2 == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    } else {
        int result = 0;

        result = (int) (product1.getPrice() - product2.getPrice());
        result = (result == 0? (int) (product1.getReference().compareTo(product2.getReference())) : result);

        return result;
    }

}
```

}

Pero me da el siguiente error:

```
Class 'ProductOrderByPrice' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'compareTo(T)' in 'Comparable'
```

La clase no tiene que ser abstracta, y no entiendo porque me dice que debería implementar el método `compareTo`.¿No estoy ya sobrescribiendo el método asociado compare? Gracias.

Comment: Para la interfaz ``Comparable`` tienes que implementar el método ``compareTo``, para la interfaz ``Comparator`` tienes que implementar el método ``compare``

Comment: Así es. Ya lo he resuelto. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso creo que la clase que debe implementar `Comparable` es `Product` .

En la clase `Product`, implementando `Comparable<Product>` , podrás sobreescribir el metodo `compareTo` así:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Product product2) {
    // product1 seria 'this' , y si this es null te tirará la excepcion al intentar llamar a compareTo
    if (product2 == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    } else {
        int result = 0;

        result = (int) (this.getPrice() - product2.getPrice());
        result = (result == 0? (int) (this.getReference().compareTo(product2.getReference())) : result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Saludos !!!!!!

Comment: Gracias. No era eso, ya que Mi clase Product ya tiene implementado Comparable y sobrescribe compareTo. Pero me has ayudado a ver el problema: estaba poniendo Comparable en vez de Comparator, y es la clase ProductOrderByPrice la que tiene que implementar Product: "public class ProductOrderByPrice implements Comparator <Product>"